# Problems with function pointer used in dequeue function for a linked list queue

Tags: linux

System:  Linux
Compiler:  gcc version 4.4.6

Program is for a college level class in which the instructor specified the functions to be used in a provided class.  I can only make changes to the two files here and not to any files provided from the instructor.  The program appears to be operating correctly except for my implementation of the dequeue function. I need access to the front, rear, item, and count.  The compiler says they are out of scope.  I was able to access them from the other functions in the cpp file, but because of the different method this one uses I am stumped.  From what I've found this is a function pointer.  I've never worked with these before and the only documentation I could find on them was how to use them, but nothing about how to access members from outside the function that are not sent in.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I've been working on this for days and cannot decide how to approach the problem.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//My.h
#ifndef __LINKEDQUEUE_H__
#define __LINKEDQUEUE_H__ 

#include <ostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "task.h"
#include "queueExceptions.h"

#include <string>
#include <new>
#include "queue.h"

/*class QueueEmpty
{};

class QueueFull
{};
*/

typedef Task* ItemType;


struct NodeType {
   ItemType info;
   NodeType* next;
};

class LinkedQueue: public Queue
{
public:
  int count;
  NodeType* front;
  NodeType* rear;


  LinkedQueue();

  ~LinkedQueue();

  /**
   * Enqueue a task onto the queue
   * @param tsk The task to enqueue
   * @throws QueueFull if there is not room on the queue to place the item.
   */
  void enqueue(Task *tsk) throw (QueueFull);

  /**
   * Dequeue an element from the queue.
   * @return the front of the queue.
   * @throws QueueEmpty if there are no elements in the queue.
   */
  Task *dequeue() throw (QueueEmpty);

  /**
   * Retrieve the current number of items on the queue.
   * @return the current number of items on the queue.
   */
  size_t depth() const;


};
#endif // __LINKEDQUEUE_H__
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//my.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "linkedQueue.h"

using namespace std;

LinkedQueue::LinkedQueue()
{
  front = NULL;
  rear = NULL;
  count = 0;
}

  /**
   * Enqueue a task onto the queue
   * @param tsk The task to enqueue
   * @throws QueueFull if there is not room on the queue to place the item.
   */
  void LinkedQueue::enqueue(Task *tsk) throw (QueueFull)
{
   NodeType* newNode;
   newNode = new NodeType;
   if (newNode == NULL)
   {
     throw QueueFull();
   }
   else
   {
     newNode->info = tsk;
     newNode->next = NULL;
     if (rear == NULL)
     front = newNode;
     else
     rear->next = newNode;
     rear = newNode;
     count++;
   }
}
  /**
   * Dequeue an element from the queue.
   * @return the front of the queue.
   * @throws QueueEmpty if there are no elements in the queue.
   */
  Task LinkedQueue::*dequeue() throw (QueueEmpty)
{
  if (front == NULL) {throw QueueEmpty();}
  else
  {
    NodeType* tempPtr;
    tempPtr = front;
    item = front->info;
    front = front->next;
    if (front == NULL)
      rear = NULL;
    delete tempPtr;
    LinkedQueue::count--;
    return item;

  }
}

  /**
   * Retrieve the current number of items on the queue.
   * @return the current number of items on the queue.
   */
  size_t LinkedQueue::depth() const
{
  return count;
}

  LinkedQueue::~LinkedQueue()
{
NodeType* tempPtr;
while (front != NULL)
  {
  tempPtr = front;
  front = front->next;
  delete tempPtr;
  }
rear = NULL;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

compile errors:
g++ -g -o linkedQueue.o -Wall -Werror -c linkedQueue.cpp
linkedQueue.cpp: In function ‘Task LinkedQueue::* dequeue()’:
linkedQueue.cpp:46: error: ‘front’ was not declared in this scope
linkedQueue.cpp:51: error: ‘item’ was not declared in this scope
linkedQueue.cpp:54: error: ‘rear’ was not declared in this scope
linkedQueue.h:31: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘LinkedQueue::count’
linkedQueue.cpp:56: error: from this location
make: *** [linkedQueue.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're going to post such a long question and the code that was given to your assignment entirely, no one will be interested to take a look at it. Instead be precise on what you found out so far and the question/problem you're stuck at. Also edit the code in the post to show only the sections relevant to the specific question you want an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo.  This...

```
Task LinkedQueue::*dequeue()
```

Should be

```
Task* LinkedQueue::dequeue()
```

This has confused the compiler since the implementation doesn't match what you have in your header and it doesn't know it's part of your class.

EDIT:  In addition `item` isn't declared anywhere, but I reckon it is meant to be a local variable of type `Task*`

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that.  Thanks so much wilsonmichaelpatrick for the help.  I will continue to kick myself for that one.